# Some of my grease pencil strokes are grey while others are black?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I have a Blender file that is producing some strange Grease Pencil lines. On frame 177 my strokes turn gray, and you can really see it since I have a little color behind the head. The strokes aren't transparent. There are scenes further along in the timeline that also have grey lines, but some are black. I have no idea why.
[image]

Things I've tried:

1. I tried assigning a black lineart material to the lines
2. I tried switching between view ports and noticed the lines turn black when I'm NOT in solid viewport shading mode -- however, my colors at frame 980 turn black and darker so neither of the views are desirable on render
   [image]
   [image]

Here's the colored image in the solid viewport:
[image]

I'm mainly trying to figure out how to make all the lineart black no matter what viewport I'm in. It would also be great if I could make the colors stay the same in all the viewports too. As my grass above turns black in certain views which isn't desirable. I would love to learn why so I can adjust my file. Also, here's the file I'm working in if anyone wants to poke around: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E2e8An5EWVVtsgS6BgQFU-LziXxSdzA6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out and wanted to share what I did to fix this in case anyone else had the same issue. I went over to my material list and noticed a blank material at the very top of my list. When I clicked "new" it fixed my lineart so now it is black again. I'm still figuring out the dark color issue, but if I do find an answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had color strength for new strokes set to 60% I was able to fix it in edit mode by selecting the strokes, then using Stroke -> Normalize Opacity

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but finally was able to figure it out:
Go to the material properties of that element in *Edit Mode*, then go to its *Material Properties* and then simply change the *Base Colour*.